# Angular 6 sort JSON from observable by key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

*Note: I know how to sort a regular array of objects using `.sort()`, but this time I am stuck with an observable and I am not familiar with it.*

I am fetching a JSON array of objects with a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MockDataService {

  private dataUrl = 'assets/data';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get(filename: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.dataUrl}/${filename}`);
  }

}
```

With this service, we can just pass a filename of a json file and get an observable:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MockDataService } from '../../shared/services/mock-data.service';
import { ObservableInput } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-iconography',
  templateUrl: './iconography.component.html'
})
export class IconographyComponent implements OnInit {
  pbiMini$ = this.mockdata.get('pbi-mini-names.json');

  constructor(private mockdata: MockDataService) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

but now I need to *sort* this data by one of the object keys, e.g. "name"

```
{
  "name": "Palette",
  "code": "pbi-palette",
  "char": "&#xe937;"
},
{
  "name": "Shopping tag",
  "code": "pbi-shopping-tag",
  "char": "&#xe938;"
},
```

I have searched and I can't figure it out.  In the past, when getting JSON as a plain array that's not an observable, I have successfully used

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.pbiMini.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
}
```

But it does not work on an observable like I have now.  How is this done?

### Update

Following a suggestion, I tried

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.pbiMiniSorted$ = this.pbiMini$.pipe(
    map(array => {
      return array.sort();
    })
  );
}
```

but this fails to compile with the error:
    error TS2339: Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator to modify the value in Observable.

```
const array$ = of([2, 1, 3]);
const modified$ = array$.pipe(
  // map receives a function which receives Array and returns Array
  map(array => {
    // here you can access to the data as Array object
    return array.sort();
  }),
);
```

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: declare the interface and tell `get` it. `http.get<PbiMiniName[]>(..)`

Comment: Thanks, but way over my head.  I wound up just sorting the JSON file permanently outside of Angular.

Comment: Not really cool for @tsugitta. He gave you the right answer, you only have a type problem here like he said. Type is one of the best feature. It will help you to make more robust application. This should be the accepted answser